# event click seems not working in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have the following problem . I create a clase .save , then I add to this the event click but it no work

code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bt").click(function(){
          $("form").append("<br><label>Add Province:</label>");
          $("form").append("<input type='text'/>");
          $("form").append("<input class='save' type='button' value='Guardar'/>");             
        });
        $(".save").click(function(){
          $(this).css("background-color","red");
        });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="#">
       <button id="bt">Add Province</button>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to prevent default action from button.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Also the click event should be

```
$("form").on("click",".save", function(){
          $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

This is because the button is added dinamically to the form. The click event only can be added to already existing elements.

A little example http://jsfiddle.net/r2qx3874/2/

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain me because you need e.prenventDefault();

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain me because you need e.prenventDefault();. It 's for avoid the action post

Comment: thats because when you press a button in the form, the default action is submit, so you need to prevent that. Hope it helps. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/